# Vuemapbox markers are showing at the bottom of the page

Tags: vue.js, mapbox

I am trying to build a map application with the vuemapbox library , but the strange thing is , all the markers are showing at the bottom of the page which is strange , can any one help me with it ?

[image]

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <MglMap :accessToken="accessToken" :mapStyle="mapStyle" @load="onMapLoaded">
      <MglMarker
        :coordinates.sync="locations"
        color="blue"
        v-for="(location, index) in pins"
        :key="index"
      />
    </MglMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import Mapbox from "mapbox-gl";
import {
  MglMap,
  MglMarker
} from "vue-mapbox";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: { MglMap, MglMarker },
  data() {
    return {
      accessToken:"xxx",
      mapStyle: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
      pins: [
        [20.341979525348204, 85.8345150468384],
        [25.581627613058714, 80.87795332144299],
        [25.199370930176993, 95.86881932189225],
      ],
    };
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.$store.dispatch("set_user_location");
  },
  computed: {
    locations() {
      return this.$store.getters.getThisUserMarker;
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.mapbox = Mapbox;
  },
  methods: {
    async onMapLoaded(event) {
      // in component
      this.map = event.map;
      const asyncActions = event.component.actions;
      await asyncActions.flyTo({
        center: this.locations,
        zoom: 4,
        speed: 1,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is what i have done so far , but having this strange issue , please help , Every help is appreciated .

Comment: did you load mapbox css ?

Answer (score 0):

Make shure that you have loaded mabpox css.
Try to set height for `MglMap`

```
<MglMap
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  ...
/>
```